# Vue truncate string with clickable link for complete string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am creating a truncate string feature for my table, but i want to give user posibility to view those truncated string by clicking a link or button how to do that?

i use filter to doing truncate and add some text to indicating there is some character on those field that being truncated but have no idea how to turn those text into a clickable element so maybe i can use it to trigger tooltips or show a modal that contain complete character

```
filters: { 
    truncate: function(string, value) {
        return string.substring(0, value) + '...';
    }
  }
```

**update**
how i am using is just like any other filter, i have a `itemdata` that come from backend and just looping it trought `v-for in table

```
{{ itemdata.address | truncate(50) }}
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve it through mere filters. Filters are for common text formatting, and you want to convert a string (`...`) into an element (`<a href="">...</a>` or similar) . Maybe what you are looking for is a directive, but directives are applied to components, so you would have to show how are you using it right now so we can tell if it is possible.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-truncate-collapsed